# can not get variable inside .not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add/remove class to `.view-faq`. When someone clicks `.view-faq`, its parent selector `.f-faq` will add class name `.hidden` (and remove class name `.shown` if has). All the other `.f-faq` will add class name '`.shown`'(and remove class name `.hidden` if has).

```
<article class="panel">
    <div class="f-faq"><span>question 1</span>
        <span class="f-blurb"><br>
            Answer 1<a  href="#faq-1"><span class="view-faq">View answer</span></a>
        </span>
    </div>
</article>
<article class="panel">
    <div class="f-faq"><span>question 2</span>
        <span class="f-blurb"><br>
            Answer 2<a  href="#faq-2"><span class="view-faq">View answer</span></a>
        </span>
    </div>
</article>
<article class="panel">
    <div class="f-faq"><span>question 3</span>
        <span class="f-blurb"><br>
            Answer 3<a  href="#faq-3"><span class="view-faq">View answer</span></a>
        </span>
    </div>
</article>
```

I tried this script, it did not work.

```
$('.view-faq').click(function(){
    var current = $(this).closest('.f-blurb');
    $(".f-blub").not($(current)).removeClass('hiden').addClass('shown');
    current.removeClass('shown').addClass('hiden');
})
```

How do I get it working? Cheers.

Comment: There is syntax error there, missing closing `)`

Comment: Also `current` is already a jQuery object when assigned, theres no need to wrap it up again.

Comment: @George still it does not add class 'shown' to the others.

Comment: @Alex you can simply display all and then hide current element. See my answer with working demo [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26358516/can-not-get-variable-inside-not-working-in-jquery/26358801#26358801)

Comment: @Alex Because `'f-blub' != 'f-blurb'`: http://jsfiddle.net/2csxrgx1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5dcugd9r/7/)**

You have following problems;

1. Missing `)`
2. `f-blub` should be `fblurb`

You can use following;

```
$('.view-faq').on("click", function(){
    var current = $(this).closest('.f-blurb');
    $(".f-blurb").removeClass("hiden").addClass('shown');
    current.removeClass('shown').addClass('hiden');
});
```

Comment: It is a nice and easy way to achieve. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten a closing '`)`' in the middle line of the click event:

Your code:

```
$('.view-faq').click(function(){
    var current = $(this).closest('.f-blurb');
    $(".f-blub").not($(current).removeClass('hiden').addClass('shown');
    current.removeClass('shown').addClass('hiden');
})
```

The correct code should be (as `current` is already jq object):

```
$('.view-faq').click(function(){
    var current = $(this).closest('.f-blurb');
    $(".f-blub").not(current).removeClass('hiden').addClass('shown');   <---------
    current.removeClass('shown').addClass('hiden');
})
```

Comment: I guess should be: `$(".f-blub").not(current).removeClass('hiden').addClass('shown');` otherwise following line doesn't makes sense

Comment: Yeah @A.Wolff I am with you! Thx for the correction! I've edited the post

Comment: hi, it was my bad. I have added ), still it does not add class 'shown' to the others.

Comment: @Alex you can simply display all and then hide current element. See my answer with working demo [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26358516/can-not-get-variable-inside-not-working-in-jquery/26358801#26358801)

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite the same in this way

```
$('.view-faq').click(function () {
    var current = $(this).closest('.f-blurb');
    current
        .removeClass('shown').addClass('hiden')
        .siblings().removeClass('hiden').addClass('shown');
});
```

This way you're eliminating the need to re-select the elements having class `f-blurb` from the whole DOM, which could be a bit heavy operation.